# Arch Linux Wifi randomly stops working after restart

Tags: arch-linux, wifi

When starting arch wifi either works or doesnt work.
Even if I reboot the system without doing anything it may or may not work.

If wifi does not work the interface does not even show up when using `ip link` it also doesnt show up when using `iwctl device list`.

Running `lspci -k` shows:

```
Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 (rev 78)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 8265
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

Running `dmesg | grep firmware` shows:

```
iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 36.cablabla op_mode iwlmvm
```

At this point I have no idea what causes this issue and I would really appreciate any help.

`journalctl -u systemd-networkd` if wlan works:

```js
Starting Network Configuration...
lo: Link UP
lo: Gained carrier
Enumeration completed
Started Network Configuration
eth0: Interface name change detected, rename to enp1s0
enp1s0: Link UP
wlan0: Link UP
wlan0: Link DOWN
wlan0: Link UP
wlan0: Connected WiFi access point: WifiName
wlan0: Gained carrier
wlan0 Gained IPv6LL
Stopping Network Configuration...
systemd-networkd.service: Deactivated succesfully.
Stopped Network Configuration.
```

If wlan doesnt work:

```js
Starting Network Configuration...
lo: Link UP
lo: Gained carrier
Enumeration completed
Started Network Configuration.
```

Comment: Is this a new installation or a new issue in an existing installation? What network configuration have you put into place?

Comment: The system is like 3 - 5 days old. I installed iwd and connected to my network. I have also installed NetworkManager but I deleted that again because I was told that iwd and Network Manager dont go well together. 

I also installed dhcpcd.

Comment: Have you done `systemctl start systemd-networkd`? Also `systemctl status systemd-networkd`. `journalctl -u systemd-networkd` might be useful.

Comment: I put the result of `journalctl -u systemd-networkd` in the question because the result is too long for a comment. 

It basically just stops at `Started Network Configuration.`

Comment: What do you have in `/etc/systemd/network/`?

Comment: The folder `/etc/systemd/network/` seems to be empty.

`ls -la` output:
```
total 8 
root root 4096 Jun 2 20:32
root root 4096 Jun 4 16:44
```

Comment: check out `man systemd.network`